# Libss7 with asterisk 13

Tags: asterisk

Does anyone knows libss7 work with asterisk 13 and If yes which version of libss7 suits best?
And if libss7 doesn't work with asterisk 13 than what are the alternatives.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's documented on the Asterisk wiki - both in the [upgrade notes](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Upgrading+to+Asterisk+13#UpgradingtoAsterisk13-chan_dahdi) and in the [new features list](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/New+in+13#Newin13-chan_dahdi) for Asterisk 13.

Namely, yes, it is supported; however, due to substantial updates in both chan_dahdi and libss7, you **must** use [libss7 2.0.0](http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/libss7/libss7-2.0.0.tar.gz) or later.

Comment: Thanks @Matt for ur support... Asterisk Wiki service is temporarily down So I am unable to access it right now. I will be very grateful if u can tell me which Dahdi version goes well with asterisk 13.

Comment: I have downloaded Dahdi 2.10.0.1 Is it ok?

Comment: get dahdi-linux-complete-2.10.2+2.10.2.tar.gz instead to running - works just fine for me.